# Determine all real numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_0 = x $ converges and the associated limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If we have the function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2 + \frac{x}{3}$  and the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which is recursively specified for $n \in \mathbb{N_+}$:

$a_n =_{def} f(a_{n-1})$

(So the sequence is fixed by $a_0$)

How to determine all real numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  with $a_0 = x $ converges and the associated limits?

Comment: Step 1: Find the fixed points of the iterated map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the limits is easy: If $a$ is the limit of such a sequence, then certainly $f(a)=a$. This leads to $a=a^2+\frac13a$, i.e., $a=0$ or $a=\frac23$.

If $x>\frac23$, then $f(x)=x^2+\frac13x>\frac23x+\frac13x=x$, i.e., $a_0>\frac23$ produces a strictly increasing sequence. This could only converge to a fixpoint of $f$ that is $>\frac23$. As there is no such fixpoint, sequences starting with $a_0>\frac23$ do not converge.

If $a_0=\frac23$, the sequence is constant (and obviously the limit is $\frac23$).

If $0<x<\frac23$ then $f(x)=x^2+\frac13x>0$ and $f(x)=x^2+\frac13x<\frac23x+\frac13x=x$, so $0<a_0<\frac23$ leads to a strictly decreasing sequence. As it is bounded from below, it must converge to a fixpoint of $f$ that is $<\frac23$, i.e., the sequence converges to $0$.

If $a_0=0$, the sequence is constant and converges to $0$, obviously.

If $-\frac16\le x<0$ then $f(x)=x^2+\frac13x>\frac13 x>x$ and $f(x)=x^2+\frac13x\ļe -\frac16x+\frac13x=\frac16x<0$, so a sequence starng with $-\frac16\le a_0<0$ is strictly increasingm bounded from above by $0$, hence converges to a limit $\le 0$ and in fact converges to $0$ as that is the only fixpoint $\le 0$.

If $a_0< \frac16$ then the sequence is the same (except for tha initial term) as that starting with $-\frac13-a_0$. Using this symmetry we conclude

> We have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\frac23$ if $a_0\in\{-1,\frac23\}$. We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ if $-1<a_0<\frac23$. In all other cases, $a_n$ diverges.

Comment: What does that mean: "the sequence is the same (except for tha initial term) as that starting with $-\frac13-a_0$"? Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

for $x\in [-1,\frac{2}{3}]$ it converges. If $x=-1$ or $\frac{2}{3}$ it converges to $\frac{2}{3}$. Otherwise it converges to $0$.

For any other value of $x$ is goes to infinity.

Comment: that's what it says.